# targeting an enemy's direction towards a player game maker studio 2 DnD

Tags: drag-and-drop, game-maker-studio-2

I'm using game maker studio 2 to create a dungeon game as a programming experience, and I am trying to make an enemy target the player. since I don't understand the commands in the program, I'm using Drag and Drop to make it. I set its speed to 4 then it checks if an instance exists (since I have multiple types of player objects) then sets point direction to that player object, but it just starts going to the top left of the screen. does anyone have any idea how I can fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the X and Y values need to be updated to the instance of the targeted player's object. Im not sure with dnd but with gml you can access it from the object itself. For example if you wanted the player object's 'X' coordinate you could get it using something like this

```
objPlayer.x;
```

You may need to use a global variable though if that wont work for you (be sure to update it in a STEP event though!). Also, something else to note is that if you have multiple player objects (which it sounds like you do) then you will need to know the instance ID for that player object. To do this you can use something like this:

```
players[i] = instance_create(xx, yy, objPlayer);
```

Side note: I also agree with Steven though. I would recommend starting as simple as possible with this and add complexity to it as you get things working the way you want them to. It will save your sanity in the long run, trust me. ;)

Comment: Thanks, I wish I saw this when I was still going for it. Before I saw this answer, which I only did now, I abandoned this project and started learning unity. thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Checking if any instance exists from multiple instances is a bit tricky in Gamemaker Studio, because it needs to make a decision which one is the most close. Since it can't make that decision, it seems to follow a default point (the top-left).

So it needs to check through all player instances, and see which one is the closest, then it picks that player instance to follow. This should be done in the Step Event, because the Step Event is constantly updating.

I'm not familiar with Drag and Drop, so I'm afraid I cannot give you an example.

Check if the following mechanic works with a single instance (player) first. Once that works, then you can try with multiple instances.

Comment: I thought I misunderstood you, but I think you misunderstood me. I meant I have an if statement that checks if "PlayerRight" exists. if so it goes there. if there isn't a "PlayerRight" instance, it checks for "PlayerLeft". if it exists it goes there. if not, it goes to the next if statement. I don't have multiple of the same instance that it's checking for, It's just checking for multiple types of objects. Thanks Anyway!